# Abstract classes in Android library

Tags: android

I have an abstract Activity in an Android library (**AbstractActivity**) that is supposed to be used in other applications as the base Activity.

Since this Activity isn't supposed to be used directly, it isn't declared in the library AndroidManifest.xml file (the real reason is because the Activity is declared as abstract) and so I can't declare it in the applications AndroidManifest.xml file.

The real problem is that when I create an application that uses the library, two .apk files get deployed to the device, *Library.apk* and *Application.apk*, and when the Application.apk is started it closes with the following message in LogCat:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4709): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{foo.bar/foo.bar.ApplicationActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo.bar.ApplicationActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bec098
```

Can I reference an abstract Activity that is declared in a library and use it as the base for an Activity in a project that references this library?

Comment: I was just about to ask this question myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deploying separate APKs is probably not want you want. The APKs live in different sandboxes and cannot access each other.

If you want to reuse code, create an Android library project (in Eclipse, open properties of your library project, select Android and check "Is Library" under the library section.

Then, reference the library by clicking "Add" under the library section in the projects that use this library.

You end up with a single APK then.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since this is the way I'm doing it right now. For some reason when I deployed my application through Eclipse, there were two APKs in the device (one for the library and other for the application itself. A cleaning to the project and and update to the ADT fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The best (and correct) way to do this is to use the solution @Michael has suggested.  However, for completeness, I thought I'd offer another solution that would work with the current setup of two apk files if for some reason you want to avoid making the one apk a library.  Also note that this won't work if the activity that subclasses the `AbstractActivity` is loaded first, this will only work if the subclass is instantiated or called from another `Activity` in the same application.

In another `Activity` you can instantiate a `PathClassLoader` like so

```
PathClassLoader loader = new PathClassLoader("/data/data/com.yourlibrarypackage.apk", PathClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

And then use it to load the class you want

```
loader.loadClass("com.yourpackage.YourAbstractActivity")
```

The `loadClass` method returns a `Class<T>` object which you can ignore because it has the side-effect of making it available to other classes sharing the same memory space.  That call is akin to `Class.forName()`.

Comment: I'm accepting Michael's answer since it was the right way of doing what I wanted. I didn't intend to have two APKs at a time on the device for this specific case, but your suggestion get's noted and may come in handy in the future. Thanks for the help.